# Linux locally dropping UDP packets (Receive buffer overflow)

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, udp

I built a simple test program that sends 100 UDP packets, each of size 1000 bytes, every 250ms. I'm finding that two separate linux boxes are dropping some of these packets.

My expectation is that when I write the 100 UDP packets, the kernel buffers are able to hold on to all of these packets. `netstat -us` indicates that there are `RcvbufErrors` for every packet that gets dropped. So it seems like the kernel receive buffer is overflowing. But I don't understand why.

`/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default` shows a value of 212992, so I don't believe increasing that will help because it's already larger than the 100kB batches this test is sending.

I ran a second test where I send 50 UDP packets, each of size 1000 bytes, every 10ms. I found that *no packets* got dropped on this test. This indicates to me that 100kB overflows buffers, while 50kB does not. It also further indicates that I'm not CPU limited or packet limited -- this test sends packets many times faster than the first.

The two linux machines I used: virtualbox on a macbook, and an AWS `m5a.xlarge`.

My test program: https://github.com/theicfire/rando/tree/master/udp-fail-batch-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right on the edge of the buffer size, although it doesn't seem like it.

The value of `rmem_default` does not mean there are exactly that many bytes available to use. I got a hint of this when reading the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) for setting `SO_RECVBUF`:

```
          The kernel doubles this value (to allow space for bookkeeping
          overhead) when it is set using setsockopt(2), and this doubled
          value is returned by getsockopt(2).
```

What this means is that the kernel is taking up some part of this buffer. Perhaps a significant amount (i.e. it might be using up half of what `rmem_default` is set to.

Setting the `SO_RCVBUF` option to 125,000 stops packets from dropping. Setting it to 100,000 (a bit less than the batches of packets you're sending, due to packet headers) results in packets getting dropped. Even though the result of getsockopt is 250,000 and 200,000, respectively.

Comment: Definitely don't rely on the system's default size.  If you know up front what the size of the traffic you are going to receive is going to be, use `setsockopt()` to explicitly set the actual buffer size you will need.